# Unable to Fetch the Growl Message if we have an interval to get hide after 5 sec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am writing test cases in protractor E2E.
I want that when I run the case, and when I press save, then a Growl message is shown with success or error.

```
this.growlMessage = function () {
    return element(by.css("div[ng-bind='message.text']")).getText();
}
```

Now I am able to fetch the message if we are having error because it stays there as long it is closed.
But the success message disappears after some time automatically.
In Protractor, the case keeps waiting for the Growl to disappear and then perform the next execution. I think protractor is waiting for the growl to finish it work.

How can we wait for this and get the text ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser.wait() to wait for the growl to come. Here is how you can do it-
`browser.wait(function(){
return element(by.css("div[ng-bind='message.text']")).isPresent();//wait for the growl to appear
},10000).then(function(){//waiting 10 seconds for the growl to appear
expect(element(by.css("div[ng-bind='message.text']")).getText()).toBe("Expected growl text");
})`

The tricky part here is that this particular piece of code should start running before the growl kicks and is expected to come in the next 10 seconds (for this particular scenario).